# Silverlight whith SeparatorVisibility Collapsed in Headerstyle

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I use the property "SeparatorVisibility" with the value "Collapsed" in a datagrid column header to disable the separator between the headers.
It works fine when my zoom is "normal" in my navigator :

[image]

but when zoom is using :

[image]

The separators are visible and I don't understand why!

Here my ressource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dataprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<!--Style de l'entête double ligne sans titre au dessus-->
<Style x:Name="HeaderDoubleLine" TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader" >
    <!--"#FFC9CACA"-->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">

                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" To="#FF448DCA"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[3].Color" To="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[2].Color" To="#CCFFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[1].Color" To="#F2FFFFFF"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" To="#FF448DCA"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[0].Color" To="#D8FFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[1].Color" To="#C6FFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[2].Color" To="#8CFFFFFF"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(GradientStops)[3].Color" To="#3FFFFFFF"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SortStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unsorted"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SortAscending" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="SortDescending" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Fill="#FF1F3B53" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                        <Rectangle Margin="0,20,0,0" Fill="#FFC9CACA" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto"  Height="1" Visibility="Visible" />

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Rectangle Margin="-1,0,0,0" Fill="#FFC9CACA" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="Fill"  Width="1"  Height="20" Visibility="Visible" />
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="right"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I apply this style header on each column header that I want to change.

Comment: I thought Silverlight's an independent plug-in and it shouldn't matter what browser it's used in so should display the same in everything? Interesting...

Comment: I'm sorry after some tests, I found that it wasn't a problem of navigator. The problem appears when I use the zoom fonctionality of navigator. I Updated the subject with this new information

Comment: The only solution I found is to disable the browser zoom with the command : Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableAutoZoom = false;.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to disable the browser zoom with the command : Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableAutoZoom = false;. – Fabrice Mainguené Apr 2 at 9:43